# How to provide read backward compatibility after enabling role-based authentication in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

We are going to change cassandra setting from `authenticator: AllowAllAuthentication` to `authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator`
to enable role-based authentication. There will be two roles:

- `admin` which is a superuser
- `read-only` which is only allowed to read.

I would like to provide backward compatibility for users of the cassandra cluster. More specifically,
many users use

- shell script that uses `cqlsh`
- python cassandra package
- php cassandra package

to **only read** data from cassandra. Currently they don't specify any username or password. Therefore 
I would like to make `read-only` role some sort of a "default" role, i.e. if no username and password provided,
then the role is automatically set to `read-only` so the users can read data and thus clients don't need to change their code.

Is there a way to do this? I'm currently having trouble in the following two parts:

- the default user is `cassandra` if there is no role / user specified in `cqlsh`. I did not find a way to set default user / role.
- and for the default user `cassandra`, I still have to set a password for it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come from an oracle background, were I've done "sqlplus "/as sysdba"" for years. I like it because the O/S authenticates me. Now, there is something similar in Cassandra, but it isn't secure. Basically in your home directory there is a subdirectory called ".cassandra" (hidden). In that directory there is a file (if there isn't, create one) called "cqlshrc" (so ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc). That file you can add authentication information that will allow someone to log in by simply typing "cqlsh" without anything else (unless you're doing remote where you need "host" and "port"). The cqlshrc file has, among other things an authentication section that looks like this:

```
[authentication]
username = <your_user_name>
password = <your_password>
```

So you could simply put your desired username and password in that file and you're essentially able to connect without supplying your username and password (You could also run "cqlsh -u your_user_name" and it will find your password in your cqlshrc file as well).

You can see a few obvious issues here:
1) The password is in clear text
2) If you change the password you need to change the password in the cqlshrc file

I do not recommend you use the "cassandra" user for ANYTHING. In fact, I'd drop it. The reason is because the cassandra user does everything with CL=quorum. We found this out when investigating huge I/O requests coming from OpsCenter and our backup tool (as you can see, we use DSE). They were all using cassandra and pounding on the node(s) that had the cassandra authentication information. It's baked into the code apparently to have CL=quorum - kinda dumb. Anyway, the above is one way to have users log in with a specific user and not provide credentials making it pretty easy to switch.

Hope that helps

-Jim

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried it and it does work for `cqlsh`!! But I noticed that when I become root, I cannot use `cqlsh` directly anymore. Is there a way to do that? And also just to make sure, does this also work for other clients, for example the ones using python or php cassandra packages? I'll test the 2nd question myself but it would be great if I can get confirmation from you :)

Comment: I believe the cqlshrc is only for cqlsh, not any other type of client.  Root should be no different than any other client for cqlsh. I'm wondering if cqlsh is not in your PATH. I've tried using the same config file as root and it works fine.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much for the detailed answer! I guess my `cqlsh` path is not configured correctly. I'll check that. Thanks again!